# Connect tuxedo Services in Spring boot

Tags: spring-boot, jca, tuxedo

Is there any possibility to connect tuxedo Services in Spring boot application using Oracle JCA tuxedo resource adaptor?

Comment: Do you have to stick to Oracle JCA adaptors, or could you use Oracle JOLT: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E35855_01/tuxedo/docs12c/install/insjol.html ?

Answer (score 0):

```
You can refer below project 
https://github.com/corbtastik/joltdemo

Spring Boot to Jolt API Microservice
Project Setup
cd into src/main/resources
run install.sh to add jolt.jar to local maven repo, $ ./install.sh
confirm jolt.jar installed to: $HOME/.m2/repository/oracle/jolt/1.0/jolt-1.0.jar
References
Tuxedo Fundamentals
Oracle Tuxedo
Jolt Overview
Jolt Javadoc
Install
push jolt-web
push jolt-api
push api-gateway
test endpoints then proceed
cf create-route dev cfapps.haas-68.pez.pivotal.io --hostname jolt
cf map-route api-gateway cfapps.haas-68.pez.pivotal.io --hostname jolt
cf unmap-route api-gateway cfapps.haas-68.pez.pivotal.io --hostname api-gateway
```